# How to delete specific column in a row in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I need the following code in codeingiter.

```
mysql_query("DELETE `father_name` FROM `table` WHERE `id`='$id'");
```

So that on father name delete from the row not the whole row. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Done in codeigniter like this.

```
$data = array('father_name' => 'NULL');
$this->db->where('id', $id);        
$this->db->update('table', $data);
```

Comment: Or use array like `$this->db->update('table', array('father_name' => 'NULL'));` less lines

Comment: Please read the question properly I asked about the column in the row not  the whole row.

Comment: my answer will only update the father_name column in the row..and rest data will remain the same..and what are u getting by using my code??